# In what sense the convolution formula is described as a weighted average?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) Wikipedia article about *convolution*, it is said that: 
$$
(f*g)(t):=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau
$$
can be described as a weighted average of the function $f(\tau)$ at the moment $t$. I don't understand what the "weighted average" means here. I've seen this again and again whenever convolution is mentioned. According to [another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function) article about *weighted functions*, the "average" should be:
$$
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t-\tau)d\tau}.
$$

Could someone clarify it?

Comment: Indeed this is not always true. It is when $g\ge 0$ and $\int g(t)\, dt=1$.

Comment: It's probably better to write the convolution as $(f\ast g)(t) = \int f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\,d\tau$ when saying that. You place the weight $g(\tau)$ on the value of $f$ a distance of $\tau$ away from $t$ (in one direction), and "sum" them up. If $\int g(\tau)\,d\tau = 1$, then it is a truer "weighted average" than if $g$'s integral is $\neq 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the most important convolutions (with heat kernel or Poisson kernel) involve nonnegative functions $g$ with $\int g=1$, in which case *weighted average* is an accurate description. In general, *weighted sum* would be better. Then again, it's still a weighted average (if $g\ge 0$), up to a constant factor. In a context where a constant factor is not important    (e.g., one is interested in asymptotic behavior, or in the smoothness of $f*g$)  it is not surprising that the "weighted average" / "weighted sum" distinction is blurred.